# How to collect information about testing in cmake?

Tags: cmake

I have CMakeLists.txt with add_test macros. How to collect information about what results of test run with 'ctest' command?

Comment: Can't you just run `make test` in test folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find file `Testing/Temporary/LastTest.log` in your build directory. This file contains all information about tests.